# Extract the data along with searched string in python

Tags: python

My file (a table) actually looks like this.  I want to search for a string like "Vonmises" in the file.  Then that is the starting point of what I want to extract.  I have 9 tables like the ones shown below.  Now I can search for a "Vonmises" string in my file, but my question is how to extract the tabular data along with string.

**The code I wrote for searching 'Vonmises' string is:**

```
import re
f_read = open('filename','r')
str='VON MISES'
for line in f_read:    
    m=re.search(str,line)
    if m:
        print line
```

**My actual table:**

```
                          STRESSES IN QUADRILATERAL ELEMENT

    ELEMNT-ID GRID-ID FIB-DIS STRESSES IN ELEMNT COORD SYS PRINCIPAL STRESSES
                                Norm-X  Norm-Y  Shear-XY     Angle Major Minor Vonmises   
        1         2     45         234    4565    675         65     345   345   54345
                 43     32         444    3243    324         65     453   543   34223 

                           STRESSES IN QUADRILATERAL ELEMENT
   ELEMNT-ID GRID-ID FIB-DIS STRESSES IN ELEMNT COORD SYS PRINCIPAL STRESSES
                                 Norm-X Norm-Y Shear-XY     Angle Major Minor Vonmises   
        2        34    324        342    556     565         546    53   6543   3456
                 45    345        657    676     856         674    65   676    6766
```

**When I execute the above I code the result I get is:**

```
  ELEMNT-ID GRID-ID FIB-DIS STRESSES IN ELEMNT COORD SYS PRINCIPAL STRESSES

  ELEMNT-ID GRID-ID FIB-DIS STRESSES IN ELEMNT COORD SYS PRINCIPAL STRESSES
```

So what I want is, along with the above result, to also get tabular values and I want to extract only the Vonmises stress column and dump that into a text file.

```
     ELEMNT-ID GRID-ID FIB-DIS STRESSES IN ELEMNT COORD SYS PRINCIPAL STRESSES
                                Norm-X  Norm-Y  Shear-XY     Angle Major Minor Vonmises   
        1         2     45         234    4565    675         65     345   345   54345
                 43     32         444    3243    324         65     453   543   34223
```

Comment: What exactly do you want to extract from the example data?

Comment: You should make use of some a priori knowledge in this case. In the lines after a line containing "Vonmises", you check if a line contains only and at least X integer strings. If it does, you take the rightmost of these values. If this is not what you need, you have to clarify which data you actually need to extract.

Comment: Do you want us to write your code for you or do you have any actual questions?

Comment: i want some hints to to write a code or some examples would appreciable